# TableauScraper library is not detecting worksheets

Tags: python, web-scraping

I've been trying to use the TableauScraper library to scrape data from this dashboard https://public.tableau.com/app/profile/salma1413/viz/MOP_2021_v1/MOP
But whenever I apply the following code on the dashboard

```
from tableauscraper import TableauScraper as TS
url = 'https://public.tableau.com/app/profile/salma1413/viz/MOP_2021_v1/MOP'
ts = TS()
ts.loads(url)
wb = ts.getWorkbook()
print(wb.getWorksheetNames())
```

it prints out an empty list, which means it didn't detect any worksheets being while there are some.

Any help in scraping the data in this dashboard would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Try to use like this:

```
from tableauscraper import TableauScraper as TS
url = 'https://public.tableau.com/app/profile/salma1413/viz/MOP_2021_v1/MOP'
ts = TS()
ts.loads(url)
ts.delayMs = 2000
wb = ts.getWorkbook()
print(wb.getWorksheetNames())
```

Comment: it gives me this error now
`AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-59-56f3f5c8c6a4> in <module>
url = 'https://public.tableau.com/app/profile/salma1413/viz/MOP_2021_v1/MOP'
ts = TS()
----> ts.loads(url)
ts.delayMs = 2000
wb = ts.getWorkbook()

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tableauscraper/TableauScraper.py in loads(self, url, params)

self.tableauData = json.loads(
--->  soup.find("textarea", {"id": "tsConfigContainer"}).text
        )


AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
`