# Python tableauscraper issue

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, tableau-api

The scraper I use to retrieve data from Tableu dashboards is broken. Now, when I try to scrape any dashboard, I get the same error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
JSONDecodeError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[1], line 5
      3 ts = TS()
      4 ts.delayMs = 2000
----> 5 ts.loads(url)

File ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tableauscraper/TableauScraper.py:79, in TableauScraper.loads(self, url, params)
     76     r = api.getTableauVizForSession(self, self.session, url)
     77     soup = BeautifulSoup(r, "html.parser")
---> 79 self.tableauData = json.loads(
     80     soup.find("textarea", {"id": "tsConfigContainer"}).text
     81 )
     83 uri = urlparse(url)
     84 self.host = "{uri.scheme}://{uri.netloc}".format(uri=uri)

File ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/json/__init__.py:346, in loads(s, cls, object_hook, parse_float, parse_int, parse_constant, object_pairs_hook, **kw)
    341     s = s.decode(detect_encoding(s), 'surrogatepass')
    343 if (cls is None and object_hook is None and
    344         parse_int is None and parse_float is None and
    345         parse_constant is None and object_pairs_hook is None and not kw):
--> 346     return _default_decoder.decode(s)
    347 if cls is None:
    348     cls = JSONDecoder

File ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/json/decoder.py:337, in JSONDecoder.decode(self, s, _w)
    332 def decode(self, s, _w=WHITESPACE.match):
    333     """Return the Python representation of ``s`` (a ``str`` instance
    334     containing a JSON document).
    335 
    336     """
--> 337     obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
    338     end = _w(s, end).end()
    339     if end != len(s):

File ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/json/decoder.py:355, in JSONDecoder.raw_decode(self, s, idx)
    353     obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
    354 except StopIteration as err:
--> 355     raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
    356 return obj, end

JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Any ideas? Here is example of code:

```
from tableauscraper import TableauScraper as TS
url = "https://public.tableau.com/views/PlayerStats-Top5Leagues20192020/OnePlayerSummary"
ts = TS()
ts.delayMs = 2000
ts.loads(url)
```

I tried to scrape data from Tableu dashboard using Tableuscraper (https://github.com/bertrandmartel/tableau-scraping)

Comment: Same issue as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73407859/tableauscraper-library-is-not-detecting-worksheets

Answer (score 0):

TableuScraper expects the website to have textarea tag with id of tsConfigContainer but the given url does not have that. And thus, the code fails.

I'd assume that this is a change in Tableau and TableauScraper has not been updated/fixed,,

Comment: I'm also thinking that there are some changes in Tableau. And thanks for opening issue in the original GitHub project.